# Create eclipse project from command line while eclipse is running?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Is it possible to create an eclipse project from the command line while an instance of eclipse is running?

A headless plugin?

Will the running instance lock the workspace from updates?

Comment: Opening a file in an editor is the only thing that can be done on the current workspace from the command line. Nothing else is supported.

Comment: What do you mean by create? Which kind of project? Are you talking about the same instance? The same workspace and if so, why? Please be more clear and describe the use case why you want to do this.

Comment: @greg-449 Opening a file in an editor from the cmd could be useful for something else I am working on..how do I do that?

Comment: The `--launcher.openFile` option opens files in the current instance